# Gate capacitance vs gate voltage for a MOSFET in LTspice

Tags: ltspice

How can I plot gate capacitance vs gate voltage in LTspice for a N-channel MOSFET?
I have to use AC analysis but I don't know how to do that? Can anyone explain it to me?

Comment: No, you don't have to use AC analysis. Why do you think you have to?

Answer (score 0):

> How can I plot gate capacitance vs gate voltage in LTspice for a N-channel MOSFET?

The *apparent* large signal gate capacitance is the ratio of gate charge \$(Q_G)\$ to gate voltage \$(V_{GS})\$.

$$C_{apparent} = \frac{Q_{G}}{V_{GS}}$$

Contrary to a perhaps common belief that the apparent gate capacitance as a function of gate to source voltage is an intrinsic property of a MOSFET, it is actually a property of a MOSFET **circuit**, and the configuration of that circuit with respect to the MOSFET drain will influence the result.

You will get different answers if:

- the drain is left unconnected
- the drain is connected to a voltage limited current source
- the drain is connected through a resistor to a fixed voltage

If you feed the gate of a MOSFET with a constant current, then the charge will change linearly with time. If you then compute the ratio of elapsed charging time to \$V_{GS}\$ you will get the apparent large signal capacitance at different values of \$V_{GS}\$.

CircuitLab can perform this calculation, and I encourage you to look at the plotting parameters for running a time domain simulation.

The apparent small signal gate capacitance is given by

$$C_{apparent(small)} = \frac{dQ_G}{dV_{GS}}$$

It may be possible to plot this in CircuitLab but I don't know how. It also may be possible to plot this in various Spice implementations. However, I again don't know how. In any event, it is the inverse of the slope of the \$V_{GD}\$ curve with time.

---

With the drain left open, we have

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fnWwfF.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image]
[image]

The horizontal axis of each graph represents gate charge \$(Q_G)\$. 1 uSec on the scale represents 1 nC (nanoCoulomb). The vertical axis of the top graph represents \$V_{GS}\$. The bottom graph represents apparent small signal gate capacitance \$(T/V_{GS})\$  at different levels of gate charge. In this graph, 1 \$n(V^{-1} s)\$ represents 1 pF capacitance.

It may be a bit hard to see, but there is a very small Miller plateau in \$V_{GS}\$ around \$V_{GS}=4V\$. At voltages below this Miller plateau, \$C_{apparent}\$ is about 755 pF. Above this voltage, \$C_{apparent}\$ is about 800 pF.

Because the horizontal axis is \$Q_G\$ and not \$V_{GS}\$, to find the value of \$C_{apparent}\$ at a given \$V_{GS}\$, one needs to use both graphs. First find the point on the plot in top graph with the desired \$V_{GS}\$. The horizontal location of this point will give you the \$Q_G\$. Then move vertically down to the bottom graph. The point on the plot of the bottom graph with which has the same horizontal coordinate (i.e. \$Q_G\$) is the point which has the corresponding \$C_{apparent}\$ value.

---

With the drain connected to a voltage limited current source, we have

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ftJqPX.png)</sup>

[image]
[image]

Again, we see a Miller plateau in the \$V_{GS}\$ plot, but this time, much wider. It starts at about \$V_{GS} = 5.4 V\$ and slopes up to about 5.85V. During that brief swing of \$V_{GS}\$, \$C_{apparent}\$ rises from about 800 pF to about 2.8 nF. After reaching a peak it falls, it declines in a curve down to about 1.4 nF at \$V_{GS}=20V\$.

---

Case of a resistor connected between drain and a constant voltage source.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fuYkzE.png)</sup>

[image]
[image]

The plot of the apparent large signal gate capacitance is very similar to the constant current constant voltage circuit. The overall shape of the curves are the same, but the particular values are different. The Miller plateau begins near \$V_{GS}=4.0\$ and slopes up to around \$V_{GS}=4.8V\$. During that swing, \$C_{apparent}\$ rises from 800 pF to about 3.36 nF. It then falls, via a curve to about 1.4 nF at \$V_{GS}=20V\$.

---

The major differences in the \$C_{apparent}\$ vs \$V_{GS}\$ characteristics between the three different circuits lie in 1) voltages of the Miller plateaus, and 2) the change in \$C_{apparent}\$ while crossing the Miller plateaus.

To summarize.

1. Open drain,  Miller plateau at \$V_{GS} = 4.0 V\$, C goes from 755 pF to 800 pf
2. Constant \$I_D\$, Miller plateau at \$V_{GS} = 5.4 V\$ to \$5.85 V\$, C goes from 800 pF to 2.8 nF
3. Resistor, Miller plateau at \$V_{GS} = 4.0 V\$ to \$4.8 V\$, C goes from 800 pF to 3.36 nF

Comment: "Contrary to a perhaps common belief that the apparent gate capacitance as a function of gate to source voltage" -- in my measurements of modern SJ VDMOS types, I've found very little C(Vgs) variation at all, independent of the circuit; instead, Coss and Crss vary jointly with Vds. This might not be true of a HEXFET like IRF530, I haven't checked. The situation is either a combination, or flipped entirely, for lateral MOS, where the MOS capacitor (Cgs as a function of Vgs) dominates. (Then circuit behavior, as above, in addition to this!)

Comment: @TimWilliams Can you give me a good "example" MOSFET, and if it is in CircuitLab's library, we can test it out. If not in CircuitLab's library, we can try LTSpice.

Comment: Alas I'd have to test a lot of LTspice models to see how they behave; I have seen from inspection, a lot of models (mostly older ones like IRF530) tend to use an erroneous Cgd(Vgd) function; it doesn't make much difference (in the 0...-10V or so range where that extension matters), but it's interesting they chose to do it that way.

Comment: Hm, regarding CircuitLab, I see no facility to plot C while sweeping V, so short of stacking curves manually, I wouldn't recommend it. That leaves SPICE.  Infineon models I believe are generally quite detailed, and something IPA60R120P7 flavor for example should prove interesting?

Comment: @TimWilliams What I did in my answer is feed a constant current into the gate, and plotted T/Vgs

Comment: That works for self capacitance, but when it's a function of a different variable?

Comment: @TimWilliams I'm not sure what your concern is. If the gate is fed with constant current, the total gate charge is going to be proportional to elapsed time.  And, gate charge divided by Vgs is apparent large signal capacitance.

Comment: I mean to measure Ciss while sweeping Vds, one cannot ramp both [Vgs and Vds] at the same time; or, you do a transient sim with a hand-made capacitance meter as such, but that would take forever to run (say, measuring Ciss at 100kHz while ramping over ~ms).